# How to use the Clementine music player?

Tags: music, clementine

I get the impression that the Clementine music player is really good -- except that I haven't been able to find any documentation on how to use it. I can glean a little of that by trial and error, but that's a painful
and inadequate way to learn it because it assumes familiarity with the underlying concepts such as playlists and how they are organized.

Is there a good guide to it somewhere? **man clementine** lists Clementine's features and lists various command line options for it, but has nothing on the user interface.

**Edit:** Under Tools, the very last item is a checkbox for "Show sidebar". That still doesn't explain anything, but at least it makes it easier to explore what is possible.

**Edit 2**: None of those sources has anything to say about how playlists work.  In particular, the wiki says nothing about how to use them or the GUI.

Comment: I guess for documentation, you have to rely on the web site.  Under the [participate](https://www.clementine-player.org/participate) tab, there seems to be a Google Group-based discussion group, etc.  Perhaps you can ask there and see if there is better documentation somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Wiki on their [official Github site](https://github.com/clementine-player/Clementine):

- https://github.com/clementine-player/Clementine/wiki